# Multi-user Geographically disperse coding

Tags: .net, open-source, cvs

I have a .NET project running. It has two developers working on the same solution from different locations.

Does anyone know of a good solution/methodology/guide/setup instructions to enable us to share code quickly, keep our code-base in sync (and compiling) but also secure.

We have numerous resources at our disposal including servers (linux and windows), websites etc but no VPN.

I understand we may need a CVS of some description? But what I am looking for is a short deployment guide to help us manage our data.

Points awarded for Open source solutions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two things.  one, a **distributed** scm, such as Git or Mercurial.  The other is a Bug tracking database, like Trac or BugZilla.  The second allows everyone to work effectively, without wasting effort when other developers are working on the same thing.  The other allows you to easily *merge* the fruits of those efforts.

Comment: Thanks - Do you know of any "If your a n00b follow this guide step by step to get this environment" pages?

Comment: Ok sorry for the late reply - here is our update, we have a SVN repository setup for SCM, and we are using Enterprise Architect (http://www.sparxsystems.com) for the bug tracking, requirements management and team communication.